# Prove that $x\mathcal{R}y\iff x^2-y^2=2(y-x)$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: proof-verification, equivalence-relations

Prove that $$x\mathcal{R}y\iff x^2-y^2=2(y-x)$$ is an equivalence relation.

---

*Reflexive.* For all $x$ we have $x^2-x^2=2(x-x)$, so $x\mathcal{R}x$.

*Symmetric.* For all $x,y$ we have \begin{align}x\mathcal{R}y&\implies x^2-y^2=2(y-x)\\&\implies(-1)(x^2-y^2)=(-1)2(y-x)\\&\implies y^2-x^2=2(x-y)\\&\implies y\mathcal{R}x.\end{align}

*Transitive.* For all $x,y,z$ we have $$\begin{cases}x\mathcal{R}y\\y\mathcal{R}z\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}x^2-y^2=2(y-x)\\y^2-z^2=2(z-y)\end{cases}\implies x^2-y^2+y^2-z^2=2(y-x)+2(z-y),$$ so $$x^2-z^2=2(y-x+z-y)=2(z-x)\implies x\mathcal{R}z.$$

Is it correct?

Comment: it looks correct

Comment: This is correct. Have you seen the theorem that, for any function $f$, the relation given by "$f(x)=f(y)$" is an equivalence relation on  the domain of $f$? The reason I ask is that, if this theorem is available, then you can apply it to the function defined by $f(x)=x^2+2x$ and get your result immediately, since $x\mathcal Ry\iff x^2+2x=y^2+2y$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thank for the answer and suggestion! Yes, I have seen that theorem $\ddot\smile$. Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct and well-presented. Good job!

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing of substance to add.*